# Firebase upload progress number going over 100 from snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

This used to work fine until very recently.

When uploading a file, I am tracking the upload progress like this:

```
        uploadImage = uri => {
            const image = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
            const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
            const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
            window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
            window.Blob = Blob;

            let uploadBlob = null;

            const imageRef = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref('categories/')
            .child(`${this.props.userData.uid}`)
            .child(`${this.state.img}`);

            const mime = this.state.isVideo ? 'video/mp4' : 'image/jpg';

            fs.readFile(image, 'base64')
            .then(data => {
                return Blob.build(data, {type: `${mime};BASE64`});
            })
            .then(blob => {
                uploadBlob = blob;
                this.uploadTask = imageRef.put(blob, {contentType: mime});

                this.uploadTask.on(
                'state_changed',
                snapshot => {
                    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
                    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
                    const progress =
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
                    this.setState({ uploadProgress: progress });
                    console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);
                    switch (snapshot.state) {
                    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                        console.log('Upload is paused');
                        break;
                    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                        console.log('Upload is running');
                        break;
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads

                },
                () => {
                    // Handle successful uploads on complete
                },
                );
            });
        };
```

Here is how I am displaying the number in my component:

```
<Text>          
  {Math.trunc(this.state.uploadProgress)}%  
 </Text>
```

I am setting the number in my components state then displaying it to the user. For some reason recently the number exceeds 100, it shows something big like 38154017 for example.

When I log the progress, I can see where it goes wrong:

```
 console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);

 LOG  Upload is 0% done
 LOG  Upload is 38.15395542514653% done
 LOG  Upload is 38.15395542514653% done
 LOG  Upload is 38154017.271191105% done
 LOG  Upload is 100% done
```

For some reason, the progress is multiplying the third log by 100? This is only happening as of about a month, and after researching people seem to still be doing it this way.

Here are the logs for the bytesTransferred and totalBytes:

```
console.log(snapshot.bytesTransferred);

LOG  bytesTransferred 0
LOG  bytesTransferred 0262144
LOG  bytesTransferred 262144
LOG  bytesTransferred 262144524288
LOG  bytesTransferred 786432
LOG  bytesTransferred 786432176078

console.log(snapshot.totalBytes);

LOG  totalBytes 962510
LOG  totalBytes 962510
LOG  totalBytes 962510
LOG  totalBytes 962510
LOG  totalBytes 962510
LOG  totalBytes 962510
LOG  totalBytes 962510
```

I don't know if firebase changed something, but whatever it is I would love to hear people's comments!

Cheers.

Comment: Please edit the question to show *all* of the code in use here, including whatever component receives the uploadProgress value, and even the log statement.  We should be able to trace everything that could possibly happen between the storage callback and the line of code that logs the message.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you, I have updated my question.

Comment: I suggest also logging the values of `snapshot.bytesTransferred` and `snapshot.totalBytes` that lead to the computation that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DougStevenson Good idea, question edited!

Comment: What do the log statements for that look like?  You should know that totalBytes is never going to change.  That's the size of the file you're uploading.

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb and state the problem is likely that the value of `bytesTransferred` is being concatenated as a string (looking at those logs), when it should be summing the current total with the latest byte transfer count as proper integers.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the log statement above the logs.

Comment: I don't see the specific lines of code that log snapshot.bytesTransferred and snapshot.totalBytes. The trick here is to figure out why those numbers are for bytesTransferred are apparently too big.

Comment: @segFault In this case I concatenated the '%' after the number

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes it seems to be a problem with bytesTransferred, I have updated my question again

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK, and file a bug report with the Firebase JS SDK GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you Doug, I’ll add an answer once I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not ideal, but a potential fix could be to just add a number based on the current progress if it reaches over 100 to make it flow and replicate an increasing upload task...

Here is what I am going to use for a temporary solution:

```
this.setState({ 
   uploadProgress: progress > 100 ? this.state.uploadProgress + 7 : progress 
});
```

I have filed a bug report on the firebase sdk and will post a better answer hopefully sometime soon...